# How to add ImageView animation only in the ImageResource

Tags: android, drawable, imagebutton

I have an ImageView in my layout.

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_3);
```

I want to have an animation only for R.drawable.blue_3 icon from left to right.

Comment: Check : http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2013/06/how-to-move-an-image-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-in-android.html

Comment: This is dosent work becouse started animation ImageButton but i wont animate imageResource

Answer (score 0):

try this its work for me....!
    make a folder in `resource` and name it `anim` and place this `xml` file

(note: this is a sample `xml` file if you want single move you want to edit it)

```
  move.xml

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-75%p"
    android:toXDelta="75%p"
    android:duration="2000" >

    </translate>

    <translate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:startOffset="800"
    android:fromXDelta="75%p"
    android:toXDelta="-75%p"
    android:duration="2000" >

   </translate>
   </set>
```

Finally add this in your code

```
  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), 
           R.anim.move);
  Image.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: This is dosent work becouse started animation ImageButton but i wont animate imageResource.

Answer (score 0):

its is not possible to only add animation to resource image not to view.

Rather you can do it by:

1.Taking any Layout in place of ImageButton.

2.Add ImageButton in Layout and then,

3.Apply animation to ImageButton.

I things your problem is to manage background of ImageButton so as par above idea you can do it the same.